# Adding elements to vector in one class doesn't apply to other classes

Tags: c++, vector

The problem is that when I add an element using `push_back` to a vector in one class, and then when I try to access that vector from another class the changes haven't been saved. No element has been added to the vector from that other class, but from the class I added it from it got added without any problems.

I've tried making it to references, and pointers, but since I'm fairly new to C++ I haven't been able to figure it out. Tried putting `&`'s and `*`'s before the variables, functions, stuff like that but nothing has been working.

Hand.h

```cpp
class Hand {
public:
    std::vector<Card>& GetDealerCards();
};
```

Hand.cpp

```cpp
std::vector<Card>& Hand::GetDealerCards() {
    return this->dealerCards;
}
```

Game.cpp

```cpp
void Game::Initialize() {
    Dealer dealer;
    dealer.DealCard(1);

    Hand hand;
    std::vector<Card> dealerCards = hand.GetDealerCards();
    std::cout << dealerCards.size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < dealerCards.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << dealerCards.size() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    Game game;
    game.Initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Dealer.cpp

```cpp
void Dealer::DealCard(int cards) {
    Hand hand;
    for (int i = 0; i < cards; i++) {
        Card card(SelectRandomElement(cardSuits, 4), SelectRandomElement(cardValues, 12));
        std::vector<Card>& dealerCards = hand.GetDealerCards();
        dealerCards.push_back(card);
    }
}
```

In the `Game` class where I'm printing out how many elements are in the `dealerCards` vector, but it still prints 0, and the changes are not applying from the other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working on two different instances of `Hand`, that's why it's not working. The `Hand` object inside `Dealer::DealCard` is not the same as the one in `Game::Initialize`.

A change like this should solve your problem, you must be careful using raw pointers though.

```
class Dealer {
public:
    Dealer() : m_hand(new Hand) {}
    ~Dealer() { delete m_hand; }

    void DealCard(int cards) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cards; i++) {
            Card card(SelectRandomElement(cardSuits, 4), SelectRandomElement(cardValues, 12));
            std::vector<Card>& dealerCards = m_hand.GetDealerCards();
            dealerCards.push_back(card);
        }
    }

    Hand* getHand() { return m_hand; }

private:
    Hand* m_hand;
}

void Game::Initialize() {
    Dealer dealer;
    dealer.DealCard(1);

    Hand* hand = dealer.getHand();
    std::vector<Card> dealerCards = hand->GetDealerCards();
    std::cout << dealerCards.size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < dealerCards.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << dealerCards.size() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you want you can even do without the `Hand` class like so:

```
class Dealer {
public:
    Dealer() {}

    void DealCard(int cards) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cards; i++) {
            m_cards.emplace_back(SelectRandomElement(cardSuits, 4), SelectRandomElement(cardValues, 12));
        }
    }

    std::vector<Card> getCards() { return m_cards; }

private:
    std::vector<Card> m_cards;
}

void Game::Initialize() {
    Dealer dealer;
    dealer.DealCard(1);

    std::vector<Card> dealerCards = dealer->getCards();
    std::cout << dealerCards.size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < dealerCards.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << dealerCards.size() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dealer dealer;
dealer.DealCard(1);

Hand hand; //hand you are interested in 
std::vector<Card> dealerCards = hand.GetDealerCards();
std::cout << dealerCards.size() << std::endl;
```

Look at this order of the code: you creating a Dealer class inside of its method DealCard you are creating a an object of hand that has no relationship or what so ever with `hand you are interested in`.

Maybe pass hand as parameter or make it an attribute, I'll write you a quick fix but it depends on your design you should write your own version.

```
void Dealer::DealCard(int cards, Hand& hand) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cards; i++) {
        Card card(SelectRandomElement(cardSuits, 4), SelectRandomElement(cardValues, 12));
        std::vector<Card>& dealerCards = hand.GetDealerCards();
        dealerCards.push_back(card);
    }
}
```

---

```
void Game::Initialize() {
    Hand hand;
    Dealer dealer;
    dealer.DealCard(1,hand);
    std::vector<Card> dealerCards = hand.GetDealerCards();
    std::cout << dealerCards.size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < dealerCards.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << dealerCards.size() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    Game game;
    game.Initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Note: I highly recommend you change the values of dealers card through a set method rather than getting it by reference and changing it. If your code grows it will be difficult to follow where that attribute got changed.

Comment: Sidenote: declaring `std::vector<Card> dealerCards` as `std::vector<Card>& dealerCards` would in this case benefit from `GetDealerCards` returning a reference. EDIT: I'm just now seeing you did that except in `Game::Initialize` :)